# Is it possible to change the name of the contributed view from VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

1. `package.json` of the VS Code extension defines custom view to show structure of the project:

   ```json
   "contributes": {
       "views": {
           "explorer": [{
               "id": "myProjectView",
               "name": "<<PROJECT NAME PLACEHOLDER>>",
               "when": "myProjectView:inProjectFolder"
           }]
       }
   },
   ```
2. `activate()` method of the extension reads project file.
   One of the file attributes is the project name.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to set this name as the view name replacing the one, defined in `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can dynamically change it via [`TreeView.title`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView.title). To do this you first have to obtain a [`TreeView`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView) instance using [`window.createTreeView()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createTreeView):

```ts
let view = vscode.window.createTreeView("myProjectView", {treeDataProvider: provider});
view.title = "New Name";
```